# Any way to set quota for Network traffic of Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm running a proxy service(shadowsocks) on google cloud, I found the traffic is kind of expensive, wondering if there is any means to set the max traffic per month to avoid over spending.

[image: cost of Egress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to set a network egress/ingress quota (no such quota even seems to exist), but you could always try to do that from within the instance itself! I know there are data capping utilities out there for Linux that will get the job done, stuff like [vnStat](https://humdi.net/vnstat/). If you want to go even more in-depth with stuff like traffic shaping, the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_traffic_control) has a decent article on it.